# Passing in prop in scoped-slot not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slot

I am trying to wrap my table inside of a slot for reusability purposes but I am having trouble with passing in my `label` prop:

My main parent component `Parent.vue`:

```
    <Table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="people"
        :search="search"
        :label="label"
    >
        <template scope="props">
        Label is: {{ label }} <!-- this label is not printing out -->
        <v-data-table :headers="props.headers" :items="people" :search="props.search">
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td>{{ props.item.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
        </template>
    </Table>
```

My `Table` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :items="items" :headers="headers" :search="search" scoped-slot="{label: label}"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
          label: "Some label"
      }
    },
    computed: {

    },
    props: ["items", "headers", "search"]
  }

</script>
```

This method gives me error `Property or method "label" is not defined`. Could someone help point out where I am going wrong with passing in the `label` prop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access it as `props.label` instead of just `label`

```
<template slot-scope="slotProps">
  Label is: {{ slotProps.label }} <!-- this label is not printing out -->
  <v-data-table :headers="props.headers" :items="people" :search="props.search">
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

and in Table component, passing `label` as simple as other binding value:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :items="items" :headers="headers" :search="search" :label="label"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```